# layer.materialize() does not copy all features

Tags: pyqgis

I have a problem creating a copy of a layer in pyqgis with `layer.materialize()`. Namely, it leaves out one (or none) features from the original layer, depending on the layer.

E.g. when I run this code with a particular layer with 129 features, it consistently copies 128 of them, and always leaves out a single one:

```
new_layer = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest())
ftr = QgsFeature()
layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("jd = '4583-3809-1068-6280'")).nextFeature(ftr)
print("Original:", ftr.isValid())
new_layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("jd = '4583-3809-1068-6280'")).nextFeature(ftr)
print("     New:", ftr.isValid())
```

produces

```
Original got the SEK: True
     New got the SEK: False
```

When I run it on another layer (of the same type) with 357 features I get all of them in the new layer.

A feature is left out in about half of cases (from my dataset).

I cannot find no particularity that would distinct the one feature left out. So far I have only noticed this on layers with `QgsWkbTypes.Point` features.

No errors or warnings or anything is reported in the process...

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

*Edit:*

The workaround (at least for me) seems to be cloning the layer, writing it to a new location (which I have to anyways), and then reloading it from there:

```
new_layer = layer.clone()
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.fileEncoding = 'UTF-8'
options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
(err,e1,e2,e3) = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(new_layer, file_name, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options)
if err != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    raise Exception(f"Creating layer {name} in '{file_name}' failed: {e1} / {e2} / {e3}")
new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(file_name, name, 'ogr')
```

Comment: Can you share this layer with us?

Comment: What you apply this `new_layer = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.allFeatureIds()))`

Comment: Setting filter didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I found the cause: one of the string attributes of the left=out feature was a single character too long as per definition. As no errors are reported when creating the feature in the origin layer or when cloning/materializing the layer it was really hard to find.

`materialize()` seems to only copy the features that conform to the fields definitions.

Comment: Please file a feature request to emit a warning or something when that happens, sounds like a very hard to find issue.